# Redirect after Login, register and lost password on Wordpress to original page where users came from

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I want to change the redirect URL after login to wordpress to the same page where user logged in from. Currently I am using this code for logged in users:

```
function admin_default_page() {
  return '/new-dashboard-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Instead of [new-dashboard-url], I want them to go back to the same page where they signed in from. How to do this?

Same thing for registration and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the last page they were in, you can try something like this:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page');

function redirect_previous_page(){
    return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
```

Seems that it can be done even easier:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse126853_redirect_to_request', 10, 3 );

function wpse126853_redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
    function my_login_redirect() {
        $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_safe_redirect($location);
        exit();
    }
}
```